# Table with long column titles

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

I kept on practicing with `\multicolum` to produce the following table, which has long column titles:

[image]

This is the MEC I'm using (thank you both @mico and @technician for pointed me some remaks to improve MEC):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

% Paquetes necesarios para las tablas 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,calc}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % choose page size parameters suitably

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}

\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Descomposici\'on est\'atica del \'{\i}ndice de Theil del ingreso per c\'apita familiar}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{10}{C} @{}}
\toprule
& Participaci\'on de la fuente previsional, \%
& \'{\i}ndice de Gini de la fuente
& Correlaci\'on de la fuente con el Gini del ingreso per c\'apita familiar
& Pseudo-Gini o Concentraci\'on
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+4\tabcolsep\relax}C}{Contribuci\'on de la fuente previsional al Gini del ingreso per c\'apita familiar}
& Elasticidad de Gini & Impacto marginal
& Gini del ingreso per c\'apita familiar \\
&  &  &  &  & Absoluta & Relativa & & & \\
A\~no & $S_k$ & $G_k$ & $R_k$ & $C_k=G_kR_k$ & $S_kG_kR_k$ & $(S_kG_kR_k)/G$ & $N_k=(G_kR_k)/G$ & $S_k(N_k-1)$ & $G$      \\ \hline
\midrule
2003 & 13,6 & 0,895 & 0,575 & 0,515 & 0,070 & 0,138 & 0,002 & -0,135 & 0,507  \\
2004 & 13,5 & 0,891 & 0,563 & 0,501 & 0,067 & 0,138 & 0,003 & -0,134 & 0,490  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{10}{l}{Descomposici\'on din\'amica entre los l\'{\i}mites de 2003 y 2013:} \\
Promedio e/l\'{\i}mites: & 14,6 & & 0,453 & & & & & & 0,460  \\
Variaci\'on e/l\'{\i}mites: & 2,1 & & -0,123 & & & & & & -0,094 \\
Efecto participaci\'on: & 0,0 & Efecto concentraci\'on: & -0,018 & &     \multicolumn{4}{r}{Efecto combinado absoluto:} & -0,018 \\
& & & & & \multicolumn{4}{r}{Efecto combinado relativo:} & 19\%  \\ \hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}
      \footnotesize
      \item Fuente: Elaboraci\'on propia en base a la EPH.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

That gives the following table,

[image]

Here, I'd like to align the text of the first row at the bottom of that cell and try to make understandable the text in the last part of the table, that is "Promedio e/limites", "Variacion e/limites", "Efecto participacion". What can I implement now?

Thanks,

Comment: \def\tabularxcolumn#1{b{#1}} will do it, but it will do it for every X column.  Alternatively, you can compute the column width used by tabularx and use b{} columns instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I threw in a few other tweaks as well.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

% Paquetes necesarios para las tablas 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,calc}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{B}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}b{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % choose page size parameters suitably

\newlength{\xwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}

\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Descomposici\'on est\'atica del \'{\i}ndice de Theil del ingreso per c\'apita familiar}

\setlength{\xwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-22\tabcolsep}%
\divide\xwidth by 10

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{10}{C} @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{B{\xwidth}}{Particip-aci\'on de la fuente previsio-nal, \%}
& \multicolumn{1}{B{\xwidth}}{\'{\i}ndice de Gini de la fuente}
& \multicolumn{1}{B{\xwidth}}{Correlaci\'on de la fuente con el Gini del ingreso per c\'apita familiar}
& \multicolumn{1}{B{\xwidth}}{Pseudo-Gini o Concentraci\'on}
& \multicolumn{2}{B{\dimexpr 2\xwidth+2\tabcolsep}}{Contribuci\'on de la fuente previsional al Gini del ingreso per c\'apita familiar}
& \multicolumn{1}{B{\xwidth}}{Elasticidad de Gini}
& \multicolumn{1}{B{\xwidth}}{Impacto marginal}
& \multicolumn{1}{B{\xwidth}}{Gini del ingreso per c\'apita familiar} \\[4pt]
&  &  &  &  & Absoluta & Relativa & & & \\
A\~no & $S_k$ & $G_k$ & $R_k$ & $C_k=G_kR_k$ & $S_kG_kR_k$ & \raisebox{-0.5\normalbaselineskip}{$\displaystyle \frac{S_kG_kR_k}{G}$} 
& $N_k=(G_kR_k)/G$ & $S_k(N_k-1)$ & $G$      \\ \hline
\midrule
2003 & 13,6 & 0,895 & 0,575 & 0,515 & 0,070 & 0,138 & 0,002 & -0,135 & 0,507  \\
2004 & 13,5 & 0,891 & 0,563 & 0,501 & 0,067 & 0,138 & 0,003 & -0,134 & 0,490  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{10}{l}{Descomposici\'on din\'amica entre los l\'{\i}mites de 2003 y 2013:} \\
Promedio e/l\'{\i}mites: & 14,6 & & 0,453 & & & & & & 0,460  \\
Variaci\'on e/l\'{\i}mites: & 2,1 & & -0,123 & & & & & & -0,094 \\
Efecto participaci\'on: & 0,0 & Efecto concentraci\'on: & -0,018 & &     \multicolumn{4}{r}{Efecto combinado absoluto:} & -0,018 \\
& & & & & \multicolumn{4}{r}{Efecto combinado relativo:} & 19\%  \\ \hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}
      \footnotesize
      \item Fuente: Elaboraci\'on propia en base a la EPH.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]